# In python, how do I complete this code to make sure the last variable is equal to the 'slice'?

Tags: python-3.x, slice

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
       print original
else:
       print 'empty'

new_word = word[1:]
print new_word + first + pyg
```

^ the above code is something I've tried on codeacademy as Im at a beginners level.I'm supposed to set new_word equal to the slice from the 1st index all the way to the end of new_word using [1:len(new_word)] to do this. So if I entered 'hart', it should print 'arthay'. 
 It won't let me proceed onto the next level until I set new_word equal to the slice as well.
I'm confused as to how to go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This indeed gives `arthay` for `hart`. What exactly is the question?

Comment: How do you mean? @TerryJanReedy

Comment: @Shereen So you need to display 'Enter a new word' (and repeat the process) each time `original` is different to `new_word + first + pyg`?

Answer (score 0):

```
new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + pyg
```

Answer (score 0):

The following *will* make `new_word` equal to `arthay` for word = `hart`.

```
new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
```

You should test word for non-zero length, if you are going to bother, *before* grabbing word[0].